# Checking multiple fields from mysql with jquery AJAX in one call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a page that seems to be in full working order, but I'm having major performance issues (think 30 second delay occasionally from these calls) from what I assume is throwing too many individual POST requests to the server.

Am I right in thinking that there's some way of doing it all in one call and that doing so would improve performance, and what's the easiest way of doing it? Perhaps my use of eval() is part of the problem - or maybe my webhost is just shit.

```
        function startCheckAchs(){
            //hide the loading alert
            $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
                $(this).unbind("ajaxStop");
                popup('loadingAlert');
            });
            //load lifeTimeBaked
            lifeTimeBaked = loadAch("lifetimebaked");
            loadAch("ach_started", "#achStarted", "achstarted");
            loadAch("ach_round1", "#achRound1", "achround1");
            loadAch("ach_round2", "#achRound2", "achround2");
            loadAch("ach_round3", "#achRound3", "achround3");
            if( rewards == 1) {
                loadAch("ach_baked100", "#achBaked100", "achbaked100");
                loadAch("ach_baked500", "#achBaked500", "achbaked500");
                loadAch("ach_baked1000", "#achBaked1000", "achbaked1000");
                loadAch("ach_nobread", "#achNoBread", "achnobread");
                loadAch("ach_nodough", "#achNoDough", "achnodough");
                loadAch("ach_noflour", "#achNoFlour", "achnoflour");
                loadAch("ach_allach", "#achAllAch", "achallach");
            }
        }

function loadAch(ach, achDiv, achVar){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/loadach.php",
                data: {"achievement" : ach},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(result){
                    if ( achDiv && achVar && result == 1){
                        $(achDiv).show();
                        eval(achVar + " = 1");
                        return result;
                    } else {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Loadach.php:

```
$achievement=trim($_POST['achievement']);
$user =  $_SESSION['userid'];

$query = "SELECT $achievement FROM breadusers WHERE userid='$user'";
$link =@mysql_query($query);
if(!$link){
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}   
echo mysql_result($link, 0);
?>
```

Comment: Also, you have a very bad [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) bug in your PHP code, created by using unescaped $_POST values directly in an SQL query.

Comment: Very good point. I'll escape that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently loading achievements individually, while you should be doing something like:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT ach_started, ach_round1 FROM breadusers WHERE userid='$user'";
$link = mysql_query($query);
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($link);

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Then, in your javascript code, parse the JSON response (setting dataType: "json" should work), loop over the returned object (has keys such as ach_started, ach_round1, etc etc), and show/hide divs as needed.

Comment: I've modified my code to use things this way and it's literally a hundred times faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have a limit on the number of concurrent server requests they can handle.

If you're using sessions, you'll also find that the server can only process a single request for each session at a time, because the session file is locked by each request, and subsequent requests must wait for it to be unlocked either when the first request finishes, or when a [`session_write_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) is issued by the executing request.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll see if passing the userid from javascript rather than relying on the session variable helps. Thanks.

Comment: If these requests don't need to change session data, then issue session_write_close() as soon as they've finished reading any session data they need... i.e. immediately after $user =  $_SESSION['userid']; and before your database query

Comment: Use the "net" tab in firebug to see the timeline for the series of requests. That can help identify hold-up points

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are going to have to redesign that.

1. SQL queries are slow.
2. Lots of requests make things slow.

See if you can group all of the data for a user in your database.  That way you can make one select for all of the data you need.

Comment: Thanks for the input. When you say "group all of the data", are you suggesting redesigning the database structure, or simply redesigning to get it all from one query?

Comment: Oh yes, looking at your query you could just select * from breadusers to get all of the fields from that table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi-dimensional array and fill it with the data needed, send the array with ajax to the php code, and then you could loop through the array in the php code and echo back the desired results.

This way you would only be making 1 ajax call each time but still get the same results. might be faster this way but i have not tested this. =)

Comment: Sounds great but I've not done any work with arrays - multi-dimensional or not - with either javascript or PHP. I'll have to do some reading.